# Array push and references

Tags: perl

I am a beginner perl programmer and I've come across a piece of code which looks as follows:

```
my @Numbers=();

push(@{$Numbers[0]},3,8,9);
push(@{$Numbers[1]},5);

print join(",",@{$Numbers[0]});
print "\n";

print join(",",@{$Numbers[1]});
print "\n";
```

I'm having difficulty in understanding what the push onto `@{$Numbers[0]}` and `@{$Numbers[1]}` is doing. Does the push automatically create array references to `[3,8,9]` and `[5]` in the `Numbers` array? I have no difficulty in understanding the syntax below, which is far more common I suppose, but I haven't come across the syntax that I've pasted above, which I guess also uses auto-vivification to populate the Numbers array with references.

```
my @Numbers=();

push(@Numbers,[3,8,9]);
push(@Numbers,[5]);

print join(",",@{$Numbers[0]});
print "\n";

print join(",",@{$Numbers[1]});
print "\n";
```

Comment: Print array or hash dumper to understand the structure. See [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper).

Comment: @vkk05 Used Data::Dumper to print the array. It looks like the first and second examples are exactly the same. Both create two references in the Numbers array. It just that the first example and syntax is uncommon - at least I haven't seen it anywhere.

Comment: The first case makes sense if you use `@Numbers` like an ordered dictionary where the _Key_ is numeric. You can then later `push @{$Numbers[$NumericKey]}, @AdditionalNumbers;` (note that it's valid to have "gaps" in the index sequence)

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol#Access-and-Printing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two features at play, and one is indeed [autovivification](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Autovivification).

---

I'll go into autovivification in a second. First, let's consider the fact that `@Numbers` is empty when we access `$Numbers[0]`. This is not a problem. Perl will automatically extend the array to include this element.<sup>[1]</sup>

```perl
my @a;
$a[3] = 123;          # ok!
print(Dumper(\@a));   # [ undef, undef, undef, 123 ]
```

This isn't what the documentation calls autovivification, but it's similar enough that some people will call it autovivification too.

---

As I mentioned, the second feature is indeed autovivification. Autovivification is the automatic creation of an anonymous variable through dereferencing. Specifically, it happens when dereferencing an undefined scalar.<sup>[2]</sup>

In this case, autovivification creates an array since `@BLOCK` is an array dereference. A reference to that array is created and stored in the previously-undef scalar.

In other words, autovivification makes

```perl
push @{ $ref }, LIST;
```

effectively equivalent to

```perl
push @{ $ref //= [] }, LIST;
```

or

```perl
if (!defined($ref)) {
   my @anon;
   $ref = \@anon;
}

push @$ref, LIST;
```

---

It was probably just a contrived example for the question, but note that the posted code is weird. We know `$Numbers[0]` and `$Numbers[1]` are undef, so we don't need `push`.

```perl
my @nums;
@{ $nums[0] } = ( 3, 8, 9 );    # Also autovivification.
@{ $nums[1] } = 5;
```

And since we know `$Numbers[0]` and `$Numbers[1]` are undef, we there's no point in relying on autovivification either.

```perl
my @nums;
$nums[0] = [ 3, 8, 9 ];
$nums[1] = [ 5 ];
```

Let's get rid of those hardcoded indexes.

```perl
my @nums;
push @nums, [ 3, 8, 9 ];
push @nums, [ 5 ];
```

And a final simplification.

```perl
my @nums = (
   [ 3, 8, 9 ],
   [ 5 ],
);
```

---

1. This only happens in an lvalue context, meaning when the referenced variable is expected to be modified/modifiable. `say $a[@a];` won't extend the array even though it accesses an element after its last element.
2. It also has to be in an lvalue context. `my @copy = @{ $undef };` will not autovivify.

Comment: You made me say "autovivification" 11 times. Make that 12.

Answer (score 1):

Use Data::Dumper to see what is happening.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;

my @Numbers=();

push(@Numbers,[3,8,9]);
push(@Numbers,[5]);

print Dumper(@Numbers);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          3,
          8,
          9
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          5
        ];
```

If you pass an array to Dumper, the elements are interpreted as multiple arguments.

Round parenthesis are arrays and rectangular parenthesis are array references. `push` works only on arrays but not on array references. See the Perl manual [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref) for details about referencing and de-referencing.

You can convert an array to an array reference with a backslash:

```
print Dumper(\@Numbers);
```

Now Dumper shows the reference with rectangular parenthesis.

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            3,
            8,
            9
          ],
          [
            5
          ]
        ];
```

You can also make Numbers a reference, but then you have to de-reference it before you pass it to push.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;

my $Numbers=[];

push(@$Numbers,[3,8,9]);
push(@$Numbers,[5]);

print Dumper($Numbers);
```

Now you will understand this:

```
push(@{$Numbers[0]},3,8,9);
```

- `$Numbers[0]` takes the first element of an array (which is a scalar).
- `@{$Numbers[0]}` de-references the scalar into an array.
- `push` appends the three scalars `3`, `8` and `9` to the de-referenced array.

This results into a creation of an array reference.

Comment: Tip: No point emptying an empty array. `my @Numbers=();` simplifies to `my @Numbers;`

Comment: Re "*Round parenthesis are arrays*", Completely false. `()` has NOTHING to do with arrays. Parens merely change precedence like they do in math. For example, `my @a = 4;`, `my @a = 4..5;`, etc We only use them in `my @a = (4, 5);` cause it would mean `(my @a = 4), 5;` otherwise. `my @a;` is the named equivalent of `[]`, not `()`.

Comment: @ikegami `$Numbers[0]` is undef. Are you sure that undef is a scalar? Or does it just deault to a scalar?

Comment: yes, an undefined scalar is a scalar. Array and hash values are scalars.

Comment: @ikegami Being a member of a container does not say anything about the type of the element. This is obvious. The question was, if it makes any sense that something undefined has a type. But it seems that Perl does it that way: "undef is a valid scalar": https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined

Comment: Re "*Being a member of a container does not say anything about the type of the element.*", Well, you don't know what the scalar contains (a number, a signed int, an unsigned int, a float, one of the allowed a combination of the previous, , undef, a reference, a PVLV or a magical scalar). But you do know it's a scalar. Specifically, it can't be an array or hash. That's why we use references (which are scalars).

Comment: @ceving Is `push(@{$Numbers[0]},3,8,9)` an example of auto-vivifivation ? Because `$Numbers[0]` is undefined, perl creates an array and then pushes 3, 8 and 9 onto it ?

Comment: @sdp, Yes. `push @{$Numbers[0]}, 3, 8, 9;` is effectively short for `push @{ $Numbers[0] //= [] }, 3, 8, 9;`, which we call autovivification. There's a step missing in the explanation at the bottom, where an array is automatically created when an undefined scalar is used as a reference.

Comment: The absence of "string" from the above list of things that can be put in a scalar is an accident. Both "upgraded strings" and "downgraded strings" should appear before "one of the allowed a combination of the previous".

Comment: @sdp Perl does not create an array, because you are pushing into something undefined. You are missing the de-referencing, which does the magic. First you have undef, then you de-reference undef. De-referencing undef results into an empty list. Then you push into this empty list. But this list does not have its own storage, it is just a view on the array ref. You add the elements to the list, but they go strait through into the array ref.

Comment: Re "*Perl does not create an array*", Perl DOES crate an array. This is called autovivification. /// Re "*De-referencing undef results into an empty list.*", No, it results in an array and a reference to that array. /// Re "*Then you push into this empty list.*", You can't push onto a list. There's no such thing. Perl does not have any kind of list data structure.

Comment: @ikegami Maybe you should write your own answer.

Comment: I wasn't going to because I thought this answer was doing a good job of explaining what the code does. But that wasn't the OP's question. They are specifically asking about autovivifcation, and you seem to be struggling with that. I have just posted an answer.

Comment: I think it's a bit disingenuous to say "`()` has NOTHING to do with arrays". Parentheses do on occasion force list context. `perl -E'@x = qw(x y z); $y = @x; say $y; ($y) = @x; say $y;'`

Comment: @tobyink "_Parentheses do on occasion force list context._"  -- Yes, but that is about _context_, what to do with values on the stack etc; it doesn't at all relate to whether there are arrays around or not.  I agree that it pushes it a bit to say "_`()` has NOTHING to do with arrays_" but it's technically correct I think.  This becomes of course a bit of a semantics discussion then...